# Android App Bundle - my key isn't accepted even though it's new

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

When I clicked `Generate Signed Bundle or APK`, I created a new Keystore and a new key, and it still complains when I try to upload the bundle:

```
Upload failed

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are enrolled in App Signing by Google Play, you should sign your APK or Android App Bundle with a new key before you upload it.
```

I *did* sign the bundle with a new key. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I did a clean and rebuild and generated the aab again, and it worked after that.